# 'input()' Python 3 'Press Any Key to Continue'

Tags: python

Screen shot of the code error
[image: Screen shot of the code error.]

I think this problem maybe because of something to do with Terminal or Visual Studio Code. I'm not sure. (Just started learning python). I am also doing this on Mac OSX

But when i try to use 'input()' as like a 'Press any key to continue i get an error saying

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Don't really know how this can be fixed.

I'm using :

Python 3.7.3

Visual Studio Code = IDE

Terminal = Running the code

```
def mainmenu():
    print("Welcome to the main menu.")

print("________________________________________________________")
print("Hello and welcome to the password checker and generator.")
print("________________________________________________________")
input()
mainmenu()
```

So the goal here is to able to use the 'input()' function to get the user to press a key to continue.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you're using python3? For python2 you have to use `raw_input()`

Comment: Yes i edited the code and put in a screenshot of my situation, if you see at the bottom left you'll see that it says 'python 3.7.3'. And if you look at the code error it is showing the error 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'.

Comment: your editor may show that it is using python 3 but your terminal may be using python 2. can you add `import sys; print(sys.version)` before your call to `input()`?

Comment: thank you, it now works. I had a feeling it would be something to do with terminal. going to try and use the output section instead of terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This error usually raises when using Python 2.7, as `raw_input()` is then the correct function to use. 
Consider checking whether you're using the correct version of Python!

Comment: Yes i edited the code and put in a screenshot of my situation, if you see at the bottom left you'll see that it says 'python 3.7.3'. And if you look at the code error it is showing the error 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'.